# Identify all $a \mod 35$ such that $35$ is a pseudoprime to base $a$

Tags: number-theory

> Identify all $a \mod 35$ such that $35$ is a pseudoprime to base $a$.

By defintion, $\gcd(a,n) = 1$ for $a,n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $a^{n-1} \equiv 1 \mod n$ means that $n$ is a pseudoprime to base $a$.

$G_{35}$ is the group of elements all coprime to $35$. So I have said that

$$G_{35} \cong G_5 \times G_7.$$

The order of the two isomporhic groups are $4$ and $6$ and so the order of $G_{35} = \mathrm{lcm}(4,6) = 12$. That means all divisors of $12$ will be potential orders of $a$. I want all the $a$ such that $a^{34} = 1 \mod 35$. By Eulers theorem, this tells me that the order of this element is $\gcd(12,34) = 2$. So I want all elements of order $2$ in $G_5$ and $G_7$. Clearly, this is only $\pm 1 \mod 5$ and $\pm 1 \mod 7$ and so all values of $a$ are of the form $\pm1 \mod 7, \pm 1 \mod 5$?

Have I done this correctly? I think I might have cheated a little with the Euler theorem bit, because normally I would say $34 \mid 12$ but seeing as $34$ doesn't divide $12$ and $12$ doesn't divide $34$, I got a little stuck.

EDIT: Actually, I don't think I've finished the question as the answer should be $\mod 35$. So would the final answer just be $\pm 1 \mod 35$?

Comment: There are two more solutions, the "mixed" ones. Solve $x\equiv -1\pmod{5}$, x\equiv 1\pmod{7}$. The other one is just the negative.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh, so once I have these conditions, I still have to solve them for $x$? I.e chinese remainder theorem (unless it's easy to spot). Also, was my $\gcd$ "cheat" correct?

Comment: Well, there was a typo, you wanted gcd of 34 and 12. And sure, it is CRT for big numbers, easy with no machinery for $35$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will use standard elementary number theory terminology, not group terminology, but that makes no difference.

We want to characterize those  $a$ such that $a^{34}\equiv 1\pmod{35}$.  For such an $a$, the order of $a$ modulo $35$ must divide $34$. It must also divide $\varphi(5)$ and $\varphi(7)$, giving the possibilities $1$ or $2$. And it is clear that if $a$ has order $1$ or $2$ then $a^{34}\equiv 1\pmod{35}$.

So we want to find all elements of order $1$ or $2$ modulo $35$. So we want to solve the $4$ systems of congruences $x\equiv \pm 1\pmod{5}$, $x\equiv \pm 1\pmod{7}$.

If the signs match, the solutions are obvious. For $x\equiv 1\pmod{5}$, $x\equiv -1\pmod{7}$, a short search gives $x\equiv 6\pmod{35}$. The remaining congruence then has solution $x\equiv -6$.

Comment: You mean it must divide $\varphi(7) = 6$, not $\varphi(6)$

Comment: Yes, thank you. It would have been enough to mention one of them, the $34$ restricts things so much.